# Composer private repositry in docker

Tags: php, docker, ansible, composer-php

I have a local docker environment and ansible scripts to start/stop the environment and all devs using it for development. And now I need to add the private repository as a dependency of one of the projects, so I need a way to pass developers private ssh key to docker instance and to use it by the composer to install that project (otherwise it'll prompt user/password which is not very good in ansible). To copy ssh kee I made a task like this:

```
    - name: Copy SSH private key to container
      shell: docker  cp {{pathToSshPrivateKey}} container:/home/www-data/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but how can I tell the composer to use that key?? I only found that to force using the key instead of user/password I need to run composer with `-n` but how to provide a path to that key?

Comment: Under **no circumstances** should you place a private key in the www-data directory of a website, since there are known browser extensions that happily check for that very mistake you just described

Comment: What is "the private repository" you want to add? How is this related to PHP or Composer after all?

Comment: It's for local env so I do not think there can be an issue with the private key in `www-data` folder. But the actual issue is where I need to put it for composer to use? Currently, I tried in `home/www-data/.ssh` and in `/root/.ssh` and composer can't find the key,

Comment: Nico Haase - what do you mean? It's a PHP library/package, that is why I'm adding to composer :)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following to allow me to execute composer commands with SSH access from within a docker container:

```
docker run --rm \
--user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
-v $HOME/.ssh:/var/www/.ssh:ro \
-v $HOME/.composer:/.composer \
-v $(pwd):/var/www \
custom-image-name:tag composer install -n
```